# Is my data useless for a machine learning classifier?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to use machine learning to predict/classify a set of samples with about 6 features each. My target is multilabel with 3 possible values.

I've plotted all 2-length combinations of features, with the target color coded in either green, red or blue. Looking at the plots, there's no discernible pattern or boundaries in the data ([imgur link to plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S9ZQ.jpg)).

Does that mean that no machine learning algorithm is going to work? at least not with the current data?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.

1) Simply by looking at all 2-dimensional projections of a dataset, you can not understand any relevant interactions of groups of more than 2 features. Although I do not assume so, it is possible that your classification problem is linearly seperable in a higher dimensional space.

2) Although plotting a dataset can help understand potential issues, I would not recommend to use a plot as the only decision support.

*) The images you linked only show two colors (red/blue) whereas in your question you mention three classes/values.

Instead of estimating how well your problem could be solved with machine learning models, you should instead try. 
Use some standard libraries such as [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) in Python, implement different methods (such as SVM, Random Forest) and evaluate them.

Comment: thanks @Nikolas, you can see green dots here and there, thing is, since the points are usually all concentrated on the same place, the order in which they are drawn make the last one stand out the more